# New navigation - what is the number on review queue

Tags: support, top-bar

What is this number on the review queue?

[image: Top nav with review queue number]

This could well have been there before and I've just not noticed, but as it's beside the other notifications now it seems more obvious.  What does this number refer to (it's not obvious when you click through)?

Comment: The same as the number on the old navigation. Cached and not including the close review count.

Comment: [Yes, it was there before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISChj.png). You aren't the first person to have missed it before but noticed it now. I think that's really intriguing, because very little about it has changed. Even the color is the same.

Comment: Also see [Notify users of possible reviews on toolbar](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/191638)